# Animate trajectory in a Shiny app without explicit controls

Tags: r, rgl

I'm trying to create a Shiny app to help my students learn how different MCMC samplers work. I want to have an interactive visualization where I show trajectories on a 3-dimensional space. This is my current approach to "mimic" a trajectory going from point A to point B.

```r
library(mvtnorm)
library(rgl)
library(shiny)

options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)

df_basis <- tidyr::crossing(x1 = seq(-3, 3, 0.2), x2 = seq(-3, 3, 0.2))
x1 <- df_basis$x1
x2 <- df_basis$x2
f <- mvtnorm::dmvnorm(df_basis, c(0, 0), diag(2))

ui <- fluidPage(
  registerSceneChange(),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("add_point", "Add point"),
      actionButton("remove_points", "Remove points")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      rglwidgetOutput("rglPlot", width = "100%", height = 720)
    )
  )
)

g <- function() {
  z <- matrix(f, nrow = 31)
  x <- seq(-3, 3, 0.2)
  y <- seq(-3, 3, 0.2)
  
  bg3d(col="white")
  surface3d(x, y, z, color = "grey70", alpha = 0.6)
  aspect3d(20, 20, 20)
  axes3d()
}

g()
surface <- scene3d()
close3d()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  plot3d(surface)
  dev <- cur3d()
  save <- options(rgl.inShiny = TRUE)
  on.exit(options(save))
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    set3d(dev)
    close3d()
  })
  
  output$rglPlot <- renderRglwidget({
    rglwidget()
  })
  
  current_points <- list()
  points_coords <- list()
  
  observeEvent(input$add_point, {
    new_point <- cbind(rmvnorm(1, c(0, 0), diag(2)), 0)
    
    if (!length(points_coords)) {
      old_point <- c(0, 0, 0)
    } else {
      old_point <- points_coords[[length(points_coords)]]
    }
    
    x1 <- old_point[1]
    y1 <- old_point[2]
    x2 <- new_point[1]
    y2 <- new_point[2]
    
    slope <- (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    intercept <- y1 - x1 * slope
    
    x_values <- seq(x1, x2, length.out = 30)
    y_values <- intercept + slope * x_values
    lines_list <- list()
    
    for (i in 2:30) {
      line <- lines3d(
        x = x_values[(i - 1):i], y = y_values[(i - 1):i], z = c(0, 0),
        color = "red"
      )
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "sceneChange", sceneChange("rglPlot", add = line)
      )
      lines_list <- append(lines_list, line)
    }

    
    point <- points3d(new_point, color = "red", size = 4)
    session$sendCustomMessage(
      "sceneChange", sceneChange("rglPlot", add = point)
    )
    current_points <<- append(current_points, point)
    points_coords[[length(points_coords) + 1]] <<- new_point
    
    session$sendCustomMessage(
      "sceneChange", sceneChange("rglPlot", delete = lines_list)
    )
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(
    input$remove_points, {
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "sceneChange",
        sceneChange("rglPlot", delete = current_points)
      )
      current_points <<- list()
    })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

The problem is that this is very slow and it won't scale to what I want to do.

I basically want to have the behavior shown in the example in the documentation here https://dmurdoch.github.io/rgl/reference/ageControl.html, without having to use the control widgets. I don't want the user of my app to click Play so the trajectory moves. Also, trajectories will change all the time.

Does anyone have any recommendation to make it work?

I tried with `playwidget`s, `ageControl`, `subsetControl`, and many approaches to update input values in a hacky way, but nothing worked well.

**edit** just in case more context helps, I want to create something similar to the animation in the Hamiltonian Monte Carlo section at https://arogozhnikov.github.io/2016/12/19/markov_chain_monte_carlo.html

[image]

I already have everything to compute trajectories, surfaces, etc. The problem is that I can't plot them efficiently.

Comment: Using Shiny and rgl together limits your audience.  They are both complex systems, and to answer your question you need someone who knows both well --- there aren't many people like that.  I think getting the rgl part right is harder here, so I'd suggest rewriting your question with no Shiny in it, and get that working, then figure out how to move to Shiny.

Comment: @user2554330 you're right and thanks for the suggestion. It allowed me to fix the isse on my own. The solution is quite complicated as it allows usage of internal functions in rgl, Shiny, and javascript code. I still would like to share the code with others just in case someone has a similar problem. I'm planning to link the GitHub repo once it's published. Do you think that's a good approach? Would you suggest something different?

Comment: There are a few blogs where you could publish a short description of your code, or if you are more ambitious, a publication in the R Journal or some other software oriented journal.